# How to dangerously set inner html from javascript?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to set innerhtml from javascript?

I want to avoid set state because of odd behavior I am seeing where the useEffect is getting cleaned up ...

Comment: You could use document.getElementById("elementId").innerHTML = "new value", but if you're using React it's not the best practice.

Comment: How do you do that with react components?

Comment: you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attr like this `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'this is your innerHtml'}} />`. see [Dangerously setting the inner HTML](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#dangerously-setting-the-inner-html)